# java.lang.NullPointerException on a null object reference. when accessing "kelas" in firebase android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

i was trying to get this specific data from my database(kelas). What i'm doing here is to get this kelas value and  store it to `String kelas` in `getList()` and use it in `IF` to check if it have value of `10 or 11`, let say `String kelas` in `getList()` has value of `10`, if it `true` then i'm gonna store some data in recycleview(`databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DaftarMapel10");`), but it's not working, i tried to change the code but still got `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`.

As you can see in the comments, `@Yegorft` said that `String kelas = snapshot.getValue(String.class); This var is null. Make sure, that it is present in your database.` But i don't understand it, i tried to use constructor but same result.

**UPDATE**: so after read this answer [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), no result. So here's what go wrong, my path in database didn't the equal to user id(`.getUid`), so that is why my String kelas is null or throw `NullPointerException`, it didn't get the value of `kelas` in database because the `path` is wrong or not equal to `.getUid()`. So whoever get the same problem like me, pls check the path in your database and the code, check the `value`.

Here is my Fragment:

```
public class NilaiFragment extends Fragment {

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
String userID;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private NilaiViewModel nilaiViewModel;
DatabaseReference matchData;
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
private List<NilaiHelperClass> list;
NilaiHelperAdapter nilaiHelperAdapter;
RecyclerView nilaiRecyclerView;
DatabaseReference rootRef;
DatabaseReference yourRef;
String userid;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    nilaiViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NilaiViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nilai, container, false);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    userid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DaftarMapel10");
    matchData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AkunSiswa");

    nilaiRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.rvNilaiKelas);
    nilaiRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    nilaiRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    nilaiRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    list = new ArrayList<>();


    getList();


    return root;
}
```

Here is where the error happened:

```
    private void getList(){

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("AkunSiswa").child(userid).child("kelas").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String kelas = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if (kelas.equals("10")){
                databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                            NilaiHelperClass nilaiHelperClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(NilaiHelperClass.class);
                            list.add(nilaiHelperClass);
                        }
                        nilaiHelperAdapter = new NilaiHelperAdapter(list);
                        nilaiRecyclerView.setAdapter(nilaiHelperAdapter);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
            if (kelas.equals("11")){
                nilaiRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

this is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.skripsi.ui.Nilai.NilaiFragment$1.onDataChange(NilaiFragment.java:125)
    at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:189)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

This is my database:

[image: This is my database]

Just in case if you wanna see my databaseReference(DaftarMapel10) looks like:

[image: this is DaftarMapel10]

Comment: Don't post code as image and along with code post your logcat.

Comment: Lets start with: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788). This should let you locate code fragment in which you end up with calling `null.someMethod()` or `null.someField` or `null[index]`. After that main problem will be figuring out why was there `null` and preventing it.

Comment: String kelas = snapshot.getValue(String.class); This var is null. Make sure, that it is present in your database.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you for responding to my question Alex, sorry for my mistake. this is my first time to post here. someone already edit my database as a image, it was a form of link. i did what u told me, edit my question. Pls take a look.